# Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.net.wifi.SCAN_RESULTS flg=0x4000010 (has extras)

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to run my app on a android device a i get the following problem:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: joserafael.clienteandroid, PID: 13790
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.net.wifi.SCAN_RESULTS flg=0x4000010 (has extras) } in joserafael.clienteandroid.MainActivity$WifiReceiver@a3c37b3
at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:892)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5466)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Need ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission to get scan results
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1599)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1552)
at android.net.wifi.IWifiManager$Stub$Proxy.getScanResults(IWifiManager.java:1074)
at android.net.wifi.WifiManager.getScanResults(WifiManager.java:1318)
at joserafael.clienteandroid.MainActivity$WifiReceiver.onReceive(MainActivity.java:173)
at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:882)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5466) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Here is my Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

WifiManager mainWifi;
WifiReceiver receiverWifi;

private final Handler handler = new Handler();
ArrayList<WifiInfo> wifis = new ArrayList<WifiInfo>();

private TextView textView;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    mainWifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    receiverWifi = new WifiReceiver();
    registerReceiver(receiverWifi, new IntentFilter(
            WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
    if(mainWifi.isWifiEnabled()==false)
    {
        mainWifi.setWifiEnabled(true);
    }

    WifiManager.MulticastLock multicastLock = mainWifi.createMulticastLock("mydebuginfo");
    multicastLock.acquire();

    doInback();

    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    Button btWifi = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btWifi);
    btWifi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            saveWifiData();
        }
    });

    UDP_Server Server = new UDP_Server();
    Server.receive();
    setTextView("Access : " + Server.Message);




}

public void doInback()
{
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            mainWifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

            receiverWifi = new WifiReceiver();
            registerReceiver(receiverWifi, new IntentFilter(
                    WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
            mainWifi.startScan();
            doInback();
        }
    }, 1000);

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.add(0, 0, 0, "Refresh");
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    final ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
    int flags = 0;
    switch (v.getId()) {

    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause()
{
    unregisterReceiver(receiverWifi);
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    registerReceiver(receiverWifi, new IntentFilter(
            WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void setTextView(String msg){
    System.out.println(msg);
    textView.setText(msg);
}

public void saveWifiData()  {

    UDP_Client Client = new UDP_Client();
    //Set message
    for(WifiInfo info : wifis){
        String data =  info.toPipe();
        Client.Message += data;
    }
    Client.sender();

}

class WifiReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent)
    {

        wifis.clear();

        List<ScanResult> wifiList;
        wifiList = mainWifi.getScanResults();
        for(int i = 0; i < wifiList.size(); i++)
        {
            ScanResult wifi =  wifiList.get(i);
            WifiInfo info = new WifiInfo();
            info.setBssid(wifi.BSSID);
            info.setSignal(wifi.level);
            info.setSsid(wifi.SSID);
            info.setFrequency(wifi.frequency);
            wifis.add(info);

        }

       // setTextView("Access points found: " + wifis.size());


    }
}
}
```

I already added to manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Can you help me?

Comment: What version of Android are you testing on? What is your `targetSdkVersion`?

Comment: It is 23. (android M)

Comment: I found the permissions on SDK 23 are different. As a solution put the targetSdkVersion under 23. Thank you.